# PromQL: Filter time series based on presence of recent metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql, cadvisor

How can I filter time series to only those that have a recent metric recorded?

The specific case of this problem I'm trying to solve is this: I'm trying to graph `container_network_receive_bytes_total` from [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) to give bytes received for all *running* containers since they started running:

```
rate(
  container_network_receive_bytes_total{name=~".+",interface="eth0"}[5m]
)
```

*but only for containers that are currently running*. The problem is above query shows old terminated containers in results which I don't want. For example, some docker swarm stack broke and is in a crash loop creating new containers then terminating them every few seconds so I see a bunch of timeseries for irrelevant dead containers in the results:

[image]

I tried doing a join with the `on` operator based on current state of the container, something like:

```
rate(
  container_network_receive_bytes_total{name=~".+",interface="eth0"}[5m]) 
  + on(name) group_right 
  container_tasks_state{state="running"}
```

but this doesn't seem to work because the operator is applied with the state of the container at *each* timestamp not with the *latest* timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

`container_network_receive_bytes_total` provides the `image` label.

When a container is stopped for whatever reason, it uses the [pause container](https://groups.google.com/g/kubernetes-users/c/jVjv0QK4b_o/m/OkV5LE0mhQkJ) as placeholder (I believe this is not GKE-specific, as IBM cloud and EKS uses it too afaik).

Therefore you can filter out non-current instances using a query such as

```
rate(container_network_receive_bytes_total{name=~".+",interface="eth0",image!~"k8s.gcr.io/pause.*"}[5m]) > 0
```

after inspecting your `image` label values.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It would be great if there was some sort of "is running" label, but it's unlikely this would work without some sort of filter because at the time the metrics are being recorded containers that aren't running were running so will have the "is running" label.